# How to check privileges of users/roles on sys tables or views?

Tags: sql, oracle, roles, privileges

I want to know, who and what are the roles/users having "SELECT" access on '**dba_role_privs**' object. I am really confused as Some users can do "select on it" and some user not be able to query on this.

*I have tried this below query after referring the data dictionary (select * from dict;). It says whoever having 'SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE' can able to do "SELECT" on this 'DBA_ROLE_PRIVS'.*

```
select * from DBA_TAB_PRIVS where table_name='DBA_ROLE_PRIVS';  --SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE
```

However, after granting the privilege also, still I am not able to query on this DBA_ROLE_PRIVS.

But for some user, I can able to query on this DBA_ROLE_PRIVS even though this 'SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE' is not provided.

Could you please provide me a solution on this,

**1.How to check who are the users and roles have privilege to access this 'DBA_TAB_PRIVS '?**

**2.How to grant privilege to this 'DBA_TAB_PRIVS ' object ?**

And also provide some tips and tricks to solve and how to approach, where and all to check if problem occurs .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any user or role with the `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` system privilege, or any user or role with a direct `SELECT` grant on the view will be able to select from it.

Use the `DBA_TAB_PRIVS` view to see who has direct `SELECT` privileges, and use `DBA_SYS_PRIVS` to see which users or roles have the `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` privilege.

```
select * from dba_tab_privs where table_name='DBA_TAB_PRIVS';
select * from dba_sys_privs where privilege='SELECT ANY DICTIONARY';
```

To grant access to a view, login as a the owner (SYS, in this case), a user with SYSDBA privileges, or a user with the `GRANT ANY PRIVILEGE` or `GRANT ANY OBJECT PRIVILEGE` privileges, and use the `GRANT` command:

```
grant select on DBA_TAB_PRIVS to [username];
```

where [username] is the name of the user to which you want to grant the privilege.

Comment: I appreciate the response, it helps me to understand that any user having the role/ sys privilege can access the dba_ related views or tables.
In my case, these both two query not returning the username/role that I have ran with. My concern is that without the role/direct grant / Any sys privilege(like Any Dictionary) to the user I am querying with, how these tables are accessible to the user I ran with ?
Is there any other possibilities which I might miss, please suggest!

Comment: @Yash What roles and privileges does the user in question have?

Comment: SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE is mapped to the user who can do select on dba_role_privs. I have applied that role to other user and tried, but its not having access on dba_role_privs.

Comment: @Yash Is the role enabled for the user in the session, either explicitly with the `SET ROLE` command or implicitly by default e.g. `ALTER USER username DEFAULT ROLE ALL;`? Has the user logged in again after the role was granted? Direct object privileges take effect immediately, but new roles require a new session to take effect.

Comment: Hi, I have given that role explicitly with set command. After that i have opened new session and tried accessing dba_role_privs table. Still no luck, that table was not accessible

Comment: `set role` only applies within the current session, assuming that `grant role` had already been executed for the user and the user has then opened a new session. If you open a new session and the role is not a default role, then you must re-execute the `set role` command to activate it for that specific session.